# Packages failed to publish due to TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of null

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

In my azure devops pipeline. A conda package is build firstly and published via `UniversalPackages@0` task.

The build and upload code snippet is shown below

```
- stage: build_upload_package 
  displayName: Build and upload package
  pool:
    name: Private Agent Eve 
  jobs:
  - job: build_upload_package
    displayName: Build and Upload Package
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release'))
    container:
      image: <azureacr_repo.io>/conda:latest   //modified to remove the information
      endpoint: NameOfTheServiceConnection     //modified to remove the information
    steps:

      - bash: |
          echo "##vso[task.prependpath]$CONDA/bin"
          conda build . --output-folder $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
        displayName: Build Package
      - bash: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=packageName]$(basename $(gitRepoName))"
        displayName: Set Package Name


      - task: UniversalPackages@0  //Error appears here
        displayName: Upload to Azure Universal Packages
        inputs:
          command: publish
          publishDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
          vstsFeedPublish: 'project_1/feed_1'   //modified to remove the information
          vstsFeedPackagePublish: '$(packageName)'
          versionOption: patch
          packagePublishDescription: 'upload a Conda Package'
```

The error for Universal UniversalPackages task is show below

```
2020-11-24T17:54:48.9628862Z ##[section]Starting: Upload to Azure Universal Packages
2020-11-24T17:54:48.9645737Z ==============================================================================
2020-11-24T17:54:48.9646470Z Task         : Universal packages
2020-11-24T17:54:48.9647068Z Description  : Download or publish Universal Packages
2020-11-24T17:54:48.9647636Z Version      : 0.175.0
2020-11-24T17:54:48.9648154Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-11-24T17:54:48.9648809Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks
2020-11-24T17:54:48.9649526Z ==============================================================================
2020-11-24T17:54:49.4896147Z SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
2020-11-24T17:54:50.1267511Z Downloading: https://08wvsblobprodsu6weus73.vsblob.vsassets.io/artifacttool/artifacttool-linux-x64-Release_0.2.172.zip?sv=2019-02-02&sr=b&sig=FvnCFjIg7ZBmIapFcCcWDC1%2F7pajvzvgo0fR2Y3YYeU%3D&spr=https&se=2020-11-24T18%3A54%3A51Z&sp=r&P1=1606243791&P2=11&P3=2&P4=1nPT99OOlNXc9xNzoCS6LpVATo%2bW4fIskTJ8u6olWMk%3d
2020-11-24T17:54:56.4979070Z Caching tool: ArtifactTool 0.2.172 x64
2020-11-24T17:54:56.7183832Z SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
2020-11-24T17:54:58.7313555Z ##[error]TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of null
2020-11-24T17:54:58.7323845Z ##[error]Packages failed to publish
2020-11-24T17:54:58.7641267Z ##[section]Finishing: Upload to Azure Universal Packages
```

Question:

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Hi @SLN.  I can't fully reproduce this problem. But the PackageName variable may cause this issue. You could refer to the answer and check if it could give you some help. If it doesn't work, you could share the sample of the `gitRepoName` variable.  On the other hand , you could also hardcode a packagename with Lowercase characters and check if it could work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the error, `gitRepoName` is a template parameter, it should be accessed as `${{ gitRepoName }}` not the `$(gitRepoName)`

Comment: Hi @SLN. You can Accept your answer. This will be helpful to other users. Thanks

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT Thanks a lot for your kind remind

Answer (score 1):

I  did some tests on this task:`UniversalPackages@0`.  I noticed the following reminder in the task:

> Universal package names must be one or more lowercase alphanumeric segments separated by a dash, dot or underscore. The package name must be under 256 characters.

When your packageName contains capital letters or other special characters, this task will fail.

You could try the following scripts:

```
        - task: PowerShell@2
          inputs:
           targetType: 'inline'
           script: |
              $name = $(basename $(gitRepoName)).ToLower()
              Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=packageName]$name"

        - task: UniversalPackages@0
          inputs:
            command: 'publish'
            publishDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'          
            vstsFeedPublish: 'project_1/feed_1'
            vstsFeedPackagePublish: '$(packageName)'
            versionOption: 'patch'
```

The Powershell task could Lowercase the RepoName.

Comment: Hey Kevin, thanks a lot for the test, Al thought It is not the error caused the fail but I will definitely add the `ToLower()` call to prevent it failing for the repo that has a capital name. You in fact helped me to find a potential bug!

Comment: @SLN Awesome. Glad to know that you have found the solution and  my answer could give you some help. Feel free to accept your answer. It will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @Keivin Lu-MSFT, I found that `ToLwer()` seems not working for the code I end up using awk to do the job       - bash:  echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=projectName]$( $(ProjectName) | awk '{print tolower($0)}' )"

Comment: Thanks for sharing your method. This is also very helpful.